# Google App Engine Boilerplate help - How does it direct templates to URL path

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, boilerplate

I recently had major troubles with Google App Engine and Python as I am inexperienced, so, by luck I found GAE Boilerplate on GitHub. I started using it, and everything's fine, but I want to add another template `about.html`. How would I do that? I tried creating an HTML document in `boilerplate/templates/about.html`, and then linking to that document from the homepage via:

- `a href: /about/`
- `a href: /about.html`
- `a href: /about`
- `a href: http://fullurl.com/about.html`

But none of these seem to work. Is there a python script that acts as a handler for these types of things that I have to manually edit? I tried googling, but not much help is found for GAE boilerplate on the net, just a few docs and readmes which don't really go into much detail.

I am new to launching websites, GAE and Python script, so forgive me if this is a stupid question. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to route a path to `/about/`. From the looks of it, you have to edit the file [`boilerplate/routes.py`](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/boilerplate/routes.py).

(disclaimer: I've never used GAE Boilerplate)

First, set up the route to `/about/` by adding this line to the end of the `routes.py` file:

`_routes.append(RedirectRoute('/about/', handlers.AboutRequestHandler, name='about'))`

But you also need a controller that will dictate how the `about.html` view is displayed. Add the following code to the [`boilerplate/handlers.py`](https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/boilerplate/handlers.py) file:

```
class AboutRequestHandler(BaseHandler):
    """
    Handler to show the about page
    """

    def get(self):
        """ Returns a simple HTML form for about."""
        return self.render_template('about.html')
```

If your `about.html` file is put in the `boilerplate/templates` folder, this **should** work. I haven't tested this so I can't be sure, but you now have a route and a controller.

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver. And I must say, having not used GAE before, that's very impressive. Thank you very much!